# iOS 7 Maps: 'Directions not available, Cannot Locate The End Location'

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

I've been moving an app over to iOS 7 recently, and whilst the majority is working fine now there's a section of code that calls out to Maps to show directions. The code worked fine under iOS 6, and I can't spot any major changes but I might be missing something, I create a `MKMapItem` and store it as an instance variable and then retrieve it when the user taps on the annotation view. At that stage Maps does load, and throws the directions not available error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this a couple of times. I realised that the `MKPlacemark` I was using to create the `MKMapItem` had info in the address dictionary which wasn't matching whatever Apple could lookup.

In the end I didn't use any address information, I used only coordinates and then supplied a name to the `MKPlacemark` (to appear in the annotation in Maps).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I think it was partially down to not setting a 'full' address dictionary, which was fine for iOS 6 but not for 7. Thanks again!